# When should I use Double.longBitsToDouble(...) instead of simply casting long to a double?

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, primitive-types

I have an array of double values where the last one will be in fact a long representing time in milliseconds. Therefore this long needs to be converted to a double to fit into the array. Later at the time of retrieval of this long value it needs to be converted back to a long type. It is critical that the long value after retrieval from the array of doubles is exactly the same value (down to a one millisecond) I had before putting it into the array. There will be no operations whatsoever performed on the long value while in the array. So the questions are:

Should I simply cast the long value to double and upon retrieval cast it back to long? Will this preserve the exact value of my long?

Or should I use Double.longBitsToDouble(time) method to put the long into the array and retrieve it with Double.doubleToLongBits(time).

Or maybe I should put the long value into the array using Double.longBitsToDouble(time) and retrieve the encoded long by simply casting it to long type?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: "I have an array of double values where the last one will be in fact a long representing time in milliseconds." Stop right there. Poor design. Don't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mean, what you *should* do is to *not* use an array to represent values meaning different things...

But from what it sounds like, you have no choice but to use `Double.longBitsToDouble`, since a `double` cannot give you full precision on all `long` values.  Just casting a `long` to `double` will lose precision.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen: Wrong. `Double.doubleToRawLongBits` for backwards conversion, unless you want all values that are technically `NaN`s to get merged together.

Comment: Thank you Louis, I do agree - I should not do this, but note my comment to Evan's answer. Therefore I'll go with Double.longBitsToDouble and Double.doubleToRawLongBits.

Comment: Oh, Thanks for remark in your comment to use Double.doubleToRawLongBits to retrieve the correct value - else I would probably use Double.doubleToLongBits which wouldn't be good enough.
BTW, if such is the behavior of Double.doubleToLongBits why would anyone want to merge NaNs of two different types? I can't see usefulness of this method. Any remarks when you'd prefer doubleToLongBits over doubleToRawLongBits?

Comment: For example, if you want to test if two doubles are either equal, or are both NaN, then that's equivalent to `Double.doubleToLongBits(a) == Double.doubleToLongBits(b)`.

Comment: So if I get it right: 
Instead of saying if(a == b || (a == Double.NaN && b == Double.NAN)) I can say if(Double.doubleToLongBits(a) == Double.doubleToLongBits(b)) ?
But if that's the only reason, this method is still of doubtful usefulness.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Thanks man. Sometimes it is good to be wrong - It will provoke those in the right to share their knowledge. Else I'd be wrong too :).

Comment: You can't say `a == Double.NaN`.  Not only are there different NaNs, but NaN isn't equal to itself.  In fact, `a` is NaN if and only if `a != a`.

Comment: So is what you are saying that the expression Double.doubleToLongBits(a) == Double.doubleToLongBits(b), is the only way to check if the two doubles are equal or NaNs? If so, how is it that the Double.doubleToRawLongBits can't accomplish the same?

Comment: ...No, it's not the only way; you could also do `(a == b) || (Double.isNaN(a) && Double.isNaN(b))`.  But you can have `a` and `b` both be NaN and their `Double.doubleToRawLongBits` be different; that's what "there are different NaNs" means.  Read the Javadoc if you want the details.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a custom class that is basically a container for a `double` array and a single `long` value. You should never use arrays for storing data of different types or with the intention of using certain elements of the array for different purposes.

Example using a `List<double>`:

```
public class DoublesWithTimestampStructure
{
    private List<double> doubles;
    private long timestamp;

    public DoublesWithTimestampStructure()
    {
        this.doubles = new List<double>();
        this.timestamp = 0;
    }

    /*
    ... getter and setter methods, miscellaneous methods, etc.
    */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am considering this solution, but it might prove expensive to implement right now, as my application already relies heavily on this array (actually arrays) all over the place, and wrapping array into an object might complicate things. Apart from that this time element in the array is but an optional element, so I'll rather put in Javadoc a note that for this time value to be retrieved properly one must use Double.doubleToRawLongBits as suggested by Louis below. While yours is not the answer to my question I generally share your opinion, thus upvoted.